# Swapping 5V and GND for a 2 wire motor

Tags: motor

I have a 2-wire brushed DC motor in a servo housing which either pushes left or right (and "center" when unplugged).

To push to one side I connect a wire to 5V and the other to GND, to push to the other side I just need to swap the wires.

How can I achieve this with the arduino without any physical rewiring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need arduino motor shield.

[image: Shield]

[Click Here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AdafruitMotorShield)

Just click on above link, you find a good tutorial about arduino motor shield. I hope it might be helpful.

Comment: The pictured L293-based shield is obsolete by at least a decade, look for something with a more modern solution like a TB6612FNG to get decent performance, especially if using batteries.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to try the Arduino Motor Shield R3 and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a H-bridge, and it is what a standard Arduino motor shield does.